# Count the number of missing required fields in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Spreadsheet, used like a form, with multiple "Skills", all of which have 2 fields within them, a "required field" (used as a flag for if entry in that field is necessary) and a "Current field" (where the user provides input). I am trying to create a "Inputs Left" field which counts the number of "Required fields" which do not currently have an entry in the "Current field" across all of the fields (seen below).
[image]

To do this, I am currently using this formula (C12:P12 is the range with the values in it).

```
=COUNT(FILTER(C12:P12,ISODD(COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12)),C12:P12>0)) - COUNT(FILTER(C12:P12,ISEVEN(COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12)),C12:P12>=0))
```

The issue I am running into is when a "Skill" is not required, but a value is entered. With this formula, it counts this towards the number of inputs left, however I only want it to count towards this if it is a required field, while still allowing the user to input non-required skills (see below). In this situation, I would like to have it still show that 2 inputs a left (specifically skill 3 and 4 still need input)

[image]

I believe I could do this using a OnEdit() trigger with google scripts, but I would like to have it done using a formula if possible. I also believe I could do this with a series of normal If statements, but the actual document has many more "skills", and I believe an endless list of if statements would be hard to debug in the future. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 I mentioned in the post that I wanted it to have an "Inputs Left" field with the value 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a COUNTIFS statement:

```
=COUNTIFS(FILTER(C12:P12,ISODD(COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12))),">0",FILTER(C12:P12,ISEVEN(COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12))),"")
```

Because I imagine it's confusing why there is a ISEVEN(COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12)) (and ISODD), the reason is because I needed to do multiple of the "Inputs Left" Fields, and the "Required" field would switch between being even and odd, meaning I would need to edit the formula a lot. Using the COLUMN(C12:P12)-COLUMN(C12) normalized this, so the "Current" was always even and the "Required" was always odd.